# FxCopSdk RuleUtilities.GetDataFilePaths

Tags: fxcop, fxcop-customrules

I've been trying to use the following, but I cannot get either line to return any results:

```
var searchResults = RuleUtilities.GetDataFilePaths("BizTalkCopExclusions.txt", SearchFolders.Project);  
var searchResults = RuleUtilities.GetDataFilePaths("*", SearchFolders.All);
```

**Is it deprecated?**

I would hope the remaining methods in the RuleUtilities class would still work.

> Many of the helper methods found in RuleUtilties were removed from
>   FxCop 1.36 (source:
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc901387(v=vs.90).aspx).

**Am I missing an implementation step?**

Using dotPeak to look at the Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.dll I see the following static method, but cannot see where it is called from.  Do I need to specify an implementation of the CommonUtilities abstract class?

```
internal static void PushCommonUtilities(CommonUtilities utilities)
{
  InternalUtilities.s_commonUtilities = utilities;
}
```